Can't decode event data in Cloud Run Function with a Firestore trigger
I have deployed a 2nd Gen Cloud Run Function with a Firestore trigger, on the google.cloud.datastore.entity.v1.written event. I have used the sample code shown in Google Cloud documentation:
from cloudevents.http import CloudEvent
import functions_framework
from google.events.cloud import firestore


@functions_framework.cloud_event
def hello_firestore(cloud_event: CloudEvent) -> None:
    """Triggers by a change to a Firestore document.

    Args:
        cloud_event: cloud event with information on the firestore event trigger
    """
    firestore_payload = firestore.DocumentEventData()
    firestore_payload._pb.ParseFromString(cloud_event.data)

    print(f"Function triggered by change to: {cloud_event['source']}")

    print("\nOld value:")
    print(firestore_payload.old_value)

    print("\nNew value:")
    print(firestore_payload.value)


And here's the list of the dependencies residing in the requirements.txt file:
functions-framework==3.3.0
google-events==0.13.0
google-api-core==2.6.0
protobuf==5.28.3
cloudevents==1.9.0

However, every time a Firestore event comes in, the Cloud Run Function fails with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py", line 174, in view_func
    function(event)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py", line 70, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/workspace/main.py", line 13, in hello_firestore
    firestore_payload._pb.ParseFromString(cloud_event.data)
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message with type 'google.events.cloud.firestore.v1.DocumentEventData'

Documentation also suggests including the proto dependencies in the source, which is something I've done but this doesn't seem to solve the issue, either. I'm sharing a screenshot of the structure, in case I have placed the proto dependencies, incorrectly:

I'm running out of ideas so would appreciate any help in case anyone has experienced similar issues and managed to resolve them.

Can you try with suggestions shared in this Link by changing the DocumentEventData to EntityEventData.
